# Reverted from Gnome to Unity on Ubuntu 14.04. Now everything looks weird

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, lightdm

[image: Top right corner of my desktop]

This  is the top right corner of my desktop. The icons are completely different. Even the terminal's background has turned white.

What's happening? How can I get back the old stuff?

Comment: install unity-tweak-tool like so: `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`, and then in the theme section, select ambiance, and default icons again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your system use the wrong theme.

Install `unity-tweak-tool` :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Or install using Ubuntu Software center :

[image: Install via the software center]

---

Open it. Go in **Appearance** > **Theme** and make sure the theme is set to "**Ambiance**".

Do the same in the **Icons** tab to make sure "**Unity-icon-theme**" is selected.